# get multiple keys from keyListener

Tags: java, keylistener

I wanna to program a 2-player game, where one of them play with <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and the other one with <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>. If one of the players keeps key pressed down, `KeyListener` can't listen to other key. How should I do it so that both of them can be listened for?

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 39)
        player1.setBounds((dim_player1.width += 5), dim_player1.height, 80, 120);
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == 37)
        player1.setBounds((dim_player1.width -= 5), dim_player1.height, 80, 120);
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == 40)
        player1.setBounds(dim_player1.width, (dim_player1.height += 5), 80, 120);
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == 38)
        player1.setBounds(dim_player1.width, (dim_player1.height -= 5), 80, 120);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swing's KeyListener and multiple keys pressed at the same time.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623995/swings-keylistener-and-multiple-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time)

Comment: I saw it,but I can't understand what should I do
if (pressed.size() > 1) {
            // More than one key is currently pressed.
            // Iterate over pressed to get the keys.
        }
e.g I wanna to getKeyChar of both of key ,how should I do it it this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swing's KeyListener and multiple keys pressed at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623995/swings-keylistener-and-multiple-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

Erm. It's 6 am in my TZ, so I might be wrong, but - threading. Store the keyboard state in a thread-safe set/map, update the set/map on press event, use the state every game tick to execute the results.

Or just use a bool array. Will work as well in most cases. For example:

```
static public enum camera_action {
  ESCAPE, // e.g. exit to main menu, terminate mouse capture etc
  MV_FORWARD, MV_BACKWARD, MV_STRAFE_LEFT, MV_STRAFE_RIGHT, MV_JUMP, MV_CROUCH, // etc
}

final protected SC_HashMap<Integer, camera_action> keymap = new SC_HashMap.linked<>();
protected boolean[] action_state = new boolean[camera_action.values().length];

final protected void set_default_keymap() {
  keymap.put( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, camera_action.MV_JUMP );
  keymap.put( KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, camera_action.MV_CROUCH );
  keymap.put( KeyEvent.VK_W, camera_action.MV_FORWARD );
  keymap.put( KeyEvent.VK_S, camera_action.MV_BACKWARD );
  keymap.put( KeyEvent.VK_A, camera_action.MV_STRAFE_LEFT );
  keymap.put( KeyEvent.VK_D, camera_action.MV_STRAFE_RIGHT );
  keymap.put( KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, camera_action.ESCAPE );
}

protected void set_action_state( camera_action a, boolean new_state ) {
  action_state[a.ordinal()] = new_state;
}

protected boolean get_action_state( camera_action a ) {
  return action_state[a.ordinal()];
}

public void reset_action_state() {
  action_state = new boolean[camera_action.values().length];
}

@Override
public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {
  camera_action a = keymap.get( e.getKeyCode() );
  if ( a != null )
    set_action_state( a, true );
}

@Override
public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ) {
  camera_action a = keymap.get( e.getKeyCode() );
  if ( a != null )
    set_action_state( a, false );
}
```

I know the Oracle's policy on Enum.ordinal() - I don't give a heck about it. If EnumSet can use it, so can I. The contract of ordinal() is solid enough.

And - yeah. possible dupe of [Swing's KeyListener and multiple keys pressed at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623995/swings-keylistener-and-multiple-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time).