# Two Keys pressed at the same time in java

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a simple 2D game which contain two players. I am moving player 1 with keys W, A, S and D. Other players is controlled by arrow keys.

**The problem I am facing is that when any of the arrow key is kept pressed for moving player 2, keys W, S, D and A does work for player 1 and vice versa.**

I have seen some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623995/swings-keylistener-and-multiple-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time), but it didn't resolved my problem.

I have a main class Gameplay and made two inner class Player1Listener and Player2Listener (implementing KeyListener).

Example code for one class is shown below, other sub class looks like same.

```
private class Player1Listener implements KeyListener
{
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}      
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {    
        if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            player1right = false;
            player1left = false;
            player1down = false;
            player1up = true;       

            player1Y-=10;

        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            player1right = false;
            player1left = true;
            player1down = false;
            player1up = false;

            player1X-=10;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            player1right = false;
            player1left = false;
            player1down = true;
            player1up = false;

            player1Y+=10;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            player1right = true;
            player1left = false;
            player1down = false;
            player1up = false;

            player1X+=10;
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding these key listeners in Gameplay constructor like

```
addKeyListener(new player1Listener());
```

Comment: Use Key Bindings instead of KeyListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Threads with Key Bindings*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13999506/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private final Set<Character> Keyspressed = new HashSet<Character>(); 

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());
            if (Keyspressed.size() > 1) {
    //size is greator than one which means you
    //have pressed more than one key. 
    //now your set contains all pressed keys. iterate it and fine out which was pressed.
                   foo(Keyspressed);
                    }
                }
    public void foo(Set<Character> Keyspressed){
    boolean Apressed = false;
    boolean Wpressed = false;
    boolean Spressed = false;
    boolean Dpressed = false;

      for(Character e : Keyspressed){
      if(e==KeyEvent.VK_A){
      Apressed = true; 
      }else if(e==KeyEvent.VK_S){
      Spressed = true;
      }else if(e==KeyEvent.VK_D){
      Dpressed = true; 
      }else if(e==KeyEvent.VK_W){
      Wpressed = true;
        }
      } 
      if(Apressed && Spressed){
      //your logic
         }

      }
```

you can add all the pressed keys into a `set<Character>` and implement a function to iterate over the pressed Keys.