# How to fix Java listening to more than 1 key at a time?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, pong

Me and my partner are attempting to create the game Pong for our computer science final project. We created a reference code where 2 cubes can be controlled upwards and downwards and it works fine. The problem occurs when attempting to control both cubes at the same time (only 1 cube will move at a time). We want to make both cubes move at the same time.

WE want to say that:

```
yPos - is the y position of the black cube 
xPos - is the x position of the black cube 
xPos2 - is the x position of the blue cube
YPos2 - is the y position of the blue cube
```

Keys:

```
A - Go up for black cube
Z - Go down for black cube
K - Go up for blue cube
M - go down for blue cube
```

We have tried using a more complicated version which used j-label animation. How ever we want to make our pong game through the graphics function. But we do not understand:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PongHelpNeed extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
  // booleans to tell which key is pressed
  boolean upKey;
  boolean downKey;
  boolean upKey2;
  boolean downKey2;

  // the position variables
  int yPos;           
  int xPos; 
  int xPos2;
  int yPos2;

  public PongHelpNeed ()
  {
    //create window
    super ("Controller");
    setSize (660, 700);

    // set keys to false and original positions
    upKey = false;
    downKey = false;

    upKey2 = false;
    downKey2 = false;

    xPos = 100;
    yPos = 350;

    xPos2 = 500;
    yPos2 = 350;

    // add the frame as a listener to your keys
    addKeyListener (this);  
    // Show the frame
    setVisible(true);       
  }

  //needs to be here because the class implements KeyListener
  public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)       
  {
    System.out.println (e.getKeyCode () + " Typed");
  }

  //needs to be here because the class implements KeyListener
  public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
    //check if keys a,z or k,m are pressed

    if  (e.getKeyCode () == KeyEvent.VK_A) 
    {
      upKey = true;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode () == KeyEvent.VK_Z) 
    {
      downKey = true;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode () == KeyEvent.VK_K) 
    {
      upKey2 = true;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode () == KeyEvent.VK_M) 
    {
      downKey2 = true;
    }
    //repaint the window everytime you press a key
    repaint ();   
  } 

  //needs to be here because the class implements KeyListener
  public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) 
  {
    System.out.println (e.getKeyCode () + " Released");
  }

  //paints the pictures 
  public void paint (Graphics g)   
  {
    //set background
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 660, 700);

    //cube 1
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);      
    g.fillRect(xPos,yPos,50, 50);

    //draw cube 2
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);    
    g.fillRect(xPos2,yPos2, 50, 50);

    //if keys are pressed move the cubes accordingly up or down
    if (upKey == true)
    {
      yPos = yPos - 15;
      upKey = false;
    }

    else if (downKey == true)
    {
      yPos = yPos + 15;
      downKey = false;
    }
    else if (downKey2 == true){
      yPos2 = yPos2 + 15;
      downKey2 = false;
    }
    else if (upKey2 == true)  {
      yPos2 = yPos2 - 15;
      upKey2 = false;
    }   
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    new PongHelpNeed (); 
  }
}
```

Our expected results are we are trying to move both cube at the same time. So when we press the `A` key and the `K` key the black square should move and the blue cube should move.

Comment: have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623995/swings-keylistener-and-multiple-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

Calling `repaint()` does not trigger a call to the `paint` immediately, so it's possible that the `keyPressed` is triggered twice (or more) before `paint`.

In your `paint` method you are checking the keys in if-else, which means that if one of the flags is true, the rest are not checked. You also have a race condition where the `keyPressed` is fighting with `paint` over the flags. Also, if you press a key quickly multiple times, you'll lose all the extra key presses between the first handled event and the next repaint.

Instead of doing the move within `paint`, you should do it within the `keyPressed` handler. Don't set a flag to e.g. `upKey = true;`, but instead do the action directly: `yPos = yPos - 15;`. The `paint` method will then just refresh the view to reflect the current (updated) state.